# How can I change MySQL's root password with AMPPS?

Tags: passwords, mysql, wamp

How do I change MySQL's root password using [AMPPS](http://www.ampps.com)?

When I try to change MySQL's root password from AMPPS' home, it gives me an error saying:

> Old Password field is empty.

How can I solve this? Which password should I enter in the old password field?

Answer (score 2):

The default password is **mysql**.
You can easily change it by navigating to `http://localhost/ampps/index.php?act=mysqlsettings`

Comment: (Note : Default root password is "mysql")